# SQL Limit number of references to another table without locking

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a technique to avoid locking a row but still be able to limit the number of rows in another table that reference it?

For example:

```
create table accounts (
  id integer,
  name varchar,
  max_users integer
);

create table users (
  id integer,
  account_id integer,
  email varchar
);
```

If I want to limit the number of users that are part of an account using the `max_users` value in `accounts`. Is there another way to ensure that concurrent calls won't create more users than permitted without locking the group row?

Something like this doesn't work, since this happening in two concurrent transactions can have `select count(*)...` be true even if the count is just at the limit:

```
begin;
  insert into users(id, account_id, email)
  select 1, 1, 'john@abc.com' where (select count(*) from users where account_id = 1) < (select max_users from accounts where id = 1);
commit;
```

And the following works, but I'm having performance issues that are mostly based transactions waiting for locks:

```
begin;
  select id from accounts where id = 1 for update;
  insert into users(id, account_id, email)
    select 1, 1, 'john@abc.com' where (select count(*) from users where account_id = 1) < (select max_users from accounts where id = 1);
commit;
```

EDIT: Bonus question: what if the value is not stored in the database, but is something you can set dynamically?

Comment: This would usually be handled with a trigger.  You could store the values in an array and use a check constraint on the array.

Comment: can you elaborate? the array would be a column on the `accounts`? I'm not sure I see how you can have two concurrent transactions update the array without locking the `accounts` row (or overriding each other's write)

Comment: The serialization achieved with `for update` is necessary. Other ways to do this would have a comparable locking pattern. But look at  [asynchronous commit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-async-commit.html) to reduce latency.